# Converting CRC16 calculation from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, crc16

I have to translate a CRC16 calculation from C to C# but get the message that I cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' on the `(crc & 0x8000)` and on `return (crc & 0xFFFF)`

The code so far:

```
public unsafe short Crc16(string str)
{
    short crc = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ str[i] ^ ((crc & 0x8000) ? 0x1021 : 0);
    }
    return (crc & 0xFFFF);
}
```

EDIT: Changed char parameter to string

Original C code

```
short Crc16( char *str )
{
    short crc=0;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ *(str+i) ^ ((crc & 0x8000)? 0x1021:0 );
    return (crc & 0xffff);
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx

Comment: It would be helpful to have the original C code, there are multiple problems with this code. However, C# does not implicitly treat numeric values are booleans. If you want to test if something is zero, you must specifically test for it.

Comment: Looks like a odd CRC calculation to me.

Comment: Looks like you haven't translated this properly. My guess is that in C the parameter was "char \*" - pointer to a string, it should be translated to "string", not "char" which is an integral type. Then "(str + i)\*" becomes str[i] etc. Need original code for more definitive answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the C code.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, `0` and `FALSE` are synonymous, and any number that is not `0` is true. ([reference](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_37.htm))

To make the conversion you would do it something like this:

```
public short CalcCrc16(string str)
{
    short crc = 0;
    int i;

    unchecked
    {
        foreach(char c in str)
        {
            short exponent = (crc & 0x8000) != 0 ? 0x1021 : 0;
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ ((short)c) ^ exponent);
        }

        return (short)(crc & 0xFFFF);
    }
}
```

So now that we have the C code to work with, I changed the code sample I have here to match.  Below is the explanation of the changes:

- `char*` is the C equivalent of a string
- The `for` loop is iterating over the characters `*(str + i)` can be rewritten as `str[i]`, and is equivalent to C#'s `str.GetChar(i)`
- The ternary condition is to determine whether the exponent is 0x1021 or 0.
- I broke up the lines so you could see the algorithm a bit clearer.
- I changed `for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)` to a `foreach` on the characters because it was easier to understand.

Comment: Appreciate the help but I still cannot implicityly convert type 'int' to 'short' on the `(crc << 1) ^ ((int)c) ^ exponent)` and `return (crc & 0xFFFF)`?

Comment: `*(str + i)` is the same as `str[i]` (not `*str[i]`)

Comment: @user5825579 In C#, these operations return an `int` so you need to explicitly convert it to a `short`. For example, the last statement would become `return (short)(crc & 0xFFFF)`. Same with the assignment in the loop (and mind the parentheses).